# How to advance dates by alternate values

Tags: advdate

I use the code below to create schedules of weekly lectures (on fridays):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}

%... Set the first lecture date
\ThisYear{2019}
\ThisMonth{3}
\ThisDay{1}

\newif\iffirst
    \firsttrue
%%%
\newcommand{\nextlec}{%
  \iffirst
    \firstfalse
  \else
    \AdvanceDate[7]%
  \fi
  \section*{\today}
    \vspace{-5mm}
}

\begin{document}
\nextlec
Lecture 01.

\nextlec
Lecture 02.

\nextlec
Lecture 03.

\nextlec
Lecture 04.

\nextlec
Lecture 05.

\end{document}
```

How can I change it (still using `advdate`) if I want `\nextlec` returning a two-lectures-a-week schedule (say, on tuesdays and on thursdays)?

Comment: Can you give more information? What should this "schedule" look like? Do you mean that `\nextlec` should alternate between Tuesdays and Thursdays? I would also make it print the "Lecture X". Btw, even though you say that you want to keep using [advdate](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/advdate), the [datetime2](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) package provides much more control over dates so I'd recommend using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you want but the code below alternates between adding 2 and 5 days to the current date (as there are 2 days between Tuesday and Thursday and 5 days between Thursday and Tuesday). I've also put the "Lecture X" title into the `\nextlec` command and changed the start date of the first lecture to March 3, 2019, since this is a Tuesday. The output (for the first four lectures) is:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}

%... Set the first lecture date
\ThisYear{2019}
\ThisMonth{3}
\ThisDay{5}

\newcounter{lecture}
% make \thelecture print Lecture X, with 0-padding for lectures 1-9
\renewcommand\thelecture{%
  Lecture~\ifnum\value{lecture}<10\relax0\fi\arabic{lecture}.}
\newcount\lectureoffset% TeX counters are more convenient 
\newcommand{\nextlec}{%
  \AdvanceDate[\lectureoffset]% increase offset by 2 or 5 (initially 0)
  \ifnum\lectureoffset=2\relax\lectureoffset=5%
  \else\relax\lectureoffset=2%
  \fi%
  \refstepcounter{lecture}% increment the lecture number
  \section*{\today}\vspace{-5mm}\thelecture
}

\begin{document}

  \nextlec
  \nextlec
  \nextlec
  \nextlec
  \nextlec
  \nextlec
  \nextlec
  \nextlec
  \nextlec
  \nextlec

\end{document}
```

The key is that I have introduced the TeX counter `\lectureoffset`, which is used to print the date via `\AdvanceDate[\lectureoffset]`. Each time that `\nextlec` is used this counter is alternatively incremented by  `2` or `5`.

You could also use something like the [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgffor) package to automate this further so that, for example, to print `20` lectures you could write something like:

```
\foreach \lec in {1,...,20} \nextlec
```

For this to work you would need to add a few `\global` statements to the definition of `\nextlec`:

```
\newcommand{\nextlec}{%
  \AdvanceDate[\lectureoffset]% increase offset by 2 or 5
  \ifnum\lectureoffset=2\relax\global\lectureoffset=5%
  \else\relax\global\lectureoffset=2%
  \fi%
  \refstepcounter{lecture}% increment the lecture number
  \section*{\today}\vspace{-5mm}\thelecture
}
```